# Man, proofs, dish, city - who am I?

Tags: riddle

> A man of war;
>   Proofs at the bottom;
>   A savoury dish;
>   A capital city.

**Who am I?**
<sub>Please explain how your answer fits each line of the riddle.</sub>

Comment: Anything related to KFC or such ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Wellington - Arthur Wellesley, 1st Duke of Wellington (Napoleon war)
> Wellingtons - boots (proof at the bottom)
> Beef Wellington - a savory dish
> Wellington - capital city, New Zealand

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you please be more clear motivating the lines?

Comment: @leol2 I have expanded a bit (first version was made on mobile device, editing wasn't easy)

Comment: @leoll2 I have seen you say this multiple time, but haven't said anything yet. "Motivate" isn't the right word here - I don't know exactly what you would want, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Nice one! This is the right answer. +1 and accept :-)

Comment: @mdc32 "Motivate" means "explain why your answer is true". I often append that message to low-quality posts, which need a edit. Indeed, this post was later edited, also accepted! Without an edit, probably the author would have ignored this.

Comment: @leoll2 I know what you meant, and so do most other people, but I'm just saying that it's not the right word - "explain" would be a better fit.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's

> Bismarck

A man of war;

> Otto von Bismarck was a the first german chancellor and also a military leader

Proofs at the bottom;

> I belive this one refers to the sunken battleship

A savoury dish;

> This should be the Bismarckhering - a dish made from fish and vinegar

A capital city.

> Bismarck is the capital of North Dakota

Comment: This wasn't what I intended, but it fits everything except the 2nd line surprisingly well! +1

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a stretch, but is it

> Aquaman?

A man of war:

> Type of jellyfish, plus aquaman is leader of a particularly martial nation (soldier)

Proofs at the bottom:

> Not sure on this one yet (bottom of the ocean)

A savoury dish:

> Secret identity is Arthur Curry

A capital city:

> Atlantis (admittedly a fictional city)

Answer (score 3):

I think it could be

> Wellington

A Man of War

> Duke of Wellington, defeated Napoleon.

Proofs at the bottom

> Wellington Boots, water-proof feet.

A savoury dish

> Beef Wellingtons (yum).

A capital city

> Wellington, New Zealand.

Edit:: Dupe! So what I didn't see it.

Comment: Your answer is the same as Stefan

Comment: Oh FFS.  Well, errrm.. that one.

Comment: Well done! You got the right answer, just a bit late.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess (at the moment) is :

> KFC

A man of war

> Colonel Sanders

Proofs at the bottom

> The packaging requires oil-proofing the buckets at the bottom

A savoury dish

> The Famous Chicken

A capital city

> Kentucky ? Some Capital City which is related to KFC ?

Comment: @JLee , indeed, that is why I used "?" in my answer. Is there any way to get a Capital Reference for my answer?

Comment: Nice try, but doesn't quite work with the last line. +1 anyway